# How to place a trasperant overlay over an imageview, where the image view height will be dynamic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have an image view, I want to cover up the whole image view with a transparent overlay. I have this code snippet

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_invites_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="162dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="162dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/white_transperent80"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
                android:layout_width="94dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="ACCEPT"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRSVP"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnAccept"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="RSVP by Jul 15,2015"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/txtRsvp"></TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works fine for me with fixed **image view size** . But it's not working if I change the Imageview size dynamically and even when I changed the "layoutOverlay" width and height to "fil_parent" or "match_parent". Please help!

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it would help but maybe you can check out the new CoordinatorLayout. It lets you add dependencies between views and define behaviors so a view can react when another view changes. I believe you can change the position of the overlay when the background image changes size. Haven't used it myself so you'll have to figure it out. Hope It was of any help :)

Comment: Even I haven't tried it, anyway I will give a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It might not be possible. i've tried several ways. one horrible shortcut ive found is put the imageView with different id inside the layoutOverlay and set visibility to invisible. You wil have to set the image to both views.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_invites_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="162dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/white_transperent80"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
                android:layout_width="94dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="ACCEPT"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRSVP"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnAccept"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="RSVP by Jul 15,2015"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/txtRsvp"></TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Old Answer**
Move the imageView into layoutOverlay and set the width and height of the RelativeLayout to wrap_content. the button and text should appear on the image. Let me know if it works out. Have a nice day

Comment: The overlay will not be visible all the time. So it will be convenient if the overlay is a separate layout.

Comment: Change the layoutOverlay height to fill_parent. Please share a screenshot if it doesnt work

Comment: It might not be possible. i've tried several ways. one horrible shortcut i've found is put the imageView with different id inside the layoutOverlay and set visibility to invisible. Updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the width/height for your `layoutOverlay` RelativeLayout from fixed size to wrap_content and add the folowing to it:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/photo"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/photo"
android:layout_alignEnd="@id/photo"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/photo"
android:layout_alignStart="@id/photo"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/photo"
```